# Trying to implement back feature into my jframe using a button

Tags: java, jframe

This is my action listener that I call:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    int buttonNumber = 0;
    String buttonName;
    openJob = true;

    JButton myButton = (JButton)e.getSource();

    buttonName = myButton.getLabel();
    buttonNumber = Arrays.asList(jobs).indexOf(buttonName);

    JFrame jobFrame = new JFrame(jobs[buttonNumber]);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    MyButton backButton = new MyButton();
    JTextField field = new JTextField();

    if (Arrays.asList(jobs).contains(buttonName)){      
        jobFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        backButton.setText("Back");
        field.setText(jobDescription[buttonNumber]);
        field.setEditable(false);

        panel.add(field);
        panel.add(backButton);

        jobFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jobFrame.getContentPane().add (panel);
        jobFrame.pack();   
        jobFrame.setVisible(true);
        jobFrame.setSize(500, 500);

    }else if(buttonName.contains("Back")){
        jobFrame.setVisible(false);
        System.out.println("This is the back button");
    }
}
```

Anyway I'm trying to close the jobFrame so I don't see it when I click back and so it brings me to the previous menu.

Comment: [How to use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)